# Using python decorator with or without parentheses

Tags: python, decorator

In Python, what is the difference between using the same decorator *with and without parentheses*?

For example:

Without parentheses:

```
@some_decorator
def some_method():
    pass
```

With parentheses:

```
@some_decorator()
def some_method():
    pass
```

Comment: Great answer below. It's worth pointing out the difference is the same as the difference between `foo` and `foo()` *anywhere*, including not in a decorator.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`some_decorator` in the first code snippet is a regular decorator:

```
@some_decorator
def some_method():
    pass
```

is equivalent to

```
some_method = some_decorator(some_method)
```

On the other hand, `some_decorator` in the second code snippet is a callable that returns a decorator:

```
@some_decorator()
def some_method():
    pass
```

is equivalent to

```
some_method = some_decorator()(some_method)
```

As pointed out by Duncan in comments, some decorators are designed to work both ways. Here's a pretty basic implementation of such decorator:

```
def some_decorator(arg=None):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*a, **ka):
            return func(*a, **ka)
        return wrapper

    if callable(arg):
        return decorator(arg) # return 'wrapper'
    else:
        return decorator # ... or 'decorator'
```

[`pytest.fixture`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/2e04771893f17b571e6ab48f6884a6a70cde8fc8/_pytest/python.py#L132) is a more complex example.

Comment: It might be worth adding to your answer to mention that some decorators are written to work both ways, e.g. `@pytest.fixture` can be used directly as a decorator, or called perhaps with some named arguments in which case it returns a decorator.

Comment: What is the point of callable decorators? AFAICT, `someDecorator()` will always return the same thing, since it does not take any arguments (unless `someDecorator` holds a state). So I presume that callable decorators hold a state?

Comment: Also note that the trick mentioned by Duncan can now be entirely automated, thanks to [decopatch](https://smarie.github.io/python-decopatch/). I'm the author by the way :)

Answer (score 14):

Briefly speaking, decorators allow adding rich features to groups of functions and classes without modifying them at all.

The key to understand the difference between `@some_decorator` and `@some_decorator()` is that **the former is a decorator, while the latter is a function (or callable) that returns a decorator**.

I believe that seeing an implementation of each case facilitates understanding the difference:

#### `@some_decorator`

```
def some_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

**Application:**

```
@some_decorator
def some_method():
    pass
```

**Equivalence:**

```
some_method = some_decorator(some_method)
```

#### `@some_decorator()`

```
def some_decorator():
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

**Application:**

```
@some_decorator()
def some_method():
    pass
```

**Equivalence:**

```
some_method = some_decorator()(some_method)
```

Notice that now it is easier to see that `@some_decorator()` is a function returning a decorator while `some_decorator` is just a decorator. Keep in mind that  some decorators are written to work both ways.

So now you might be wondering why we have these two cases when the former version seems simpler. The answer is that if you want to pass arguments to a decorator, using `@some_decorator()` will allow you to do this. Let's see some code in action:

```
def some_decorator(arg1, arg2):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(arg1)
            print(arg2)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

**Application:**

```
@some_decorator('hello', 'bye')
def some_method():
    pass
```

**Equivalence:**

```
some_method = some_decorator('hello', 'bye')(some_method)
```

Note: I think that it is worth to mention that a decorator can be implemented as a function or as a class. Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-as-decorator-in-python/) for more information.

Comment: I'm confused with this answer, in your first code block for the example without parenthesis you use `args` and `kwargs` but they're not defined anywhere. In the example with parenthesis I see where they come from, but not in the example without parenthesis.

Comment: After testing I think this was just a typo, I edited the answer to make the correction.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a decorator that can be used with or without parameters, you can use the following decorator *on your decorator* to make it usable with or without parentheses, like this:

```py
>>> @omittable_parentheses(allow_partial=True)
... def multiplier(multiply_by=2):
...     def decorator(func):
...         def multiplying_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...             return multiply_by * func(*args, **kwargs)
...         return multiplying_wrapper
...     return decorator
...
>>> @multiplier
... def no_parentheses():
...     return 2
...
>>> no_parentheses()
4
>>> @multiplier()
... def parentheses():
...     return 2
...
>>> parentheses()
4
>>> @multiplier(3)
... def parameter():
...     return 2
...
>>> parameter()
6
```

If `allow_partial=True` is given, the resulting decorator will also work with with `partial`:

```py
>>> from functools import partial
>>> multiply_by_3 = partial(multiplier, multiply_by=3)
>>>
>>> @multiply_by_3
... def partial_no_parentheses():
...     return 2
...
>>> partial_no_parentheses()
6
>>> @multiply_by_3()
... def partial_parentheses():
...     return 2
...
>>> partial_parentheses()
6
```

Decorator code:

```py
from functools import wraps

def omittable_parentheses(maybe_decorator=None, /, allow_partial=False):
    """A decorator for decorators that allows them to be used without parentheses"""
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(decorator)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if len(args) == 1 and callable(args[0]):
                if allow_partial:
                    return func(**kwargs)(args[0])
                elif not kwargs:
                    return func()(args[0])
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    if maybe_decorator is None:
        return decorator
    else:
        return decorator(maybe_decorator)
```

As a bonus, this decorator decorator can be itself used with or without parentheses!

Answer (score -1):

Some actually working code where you use the arg inside decorator:

```
def someDecorator(arg=None):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*a, **ka):
            if not callable(arg):
                print (arg)
                return func(*a, **ka)
            else:
                return 'xxxxx'
        return wrapper

    if callable(arg):
        return decorator(arg) # return 'wrapper'
    else:
        return decorator # ... or 'decorator'

@someDecorator(arg=1)
def my_func():
    print('aaa')

@someDecorator
def my_func1():
    print('bbb')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_func()
    my_func1()
```

The output is:

```
1
aaa
```

Comment: This is a very nice technique, but it does not really answer the original question, which ask what the difference is between using parentheses or not.