# Is there a difference in calling a decorator e.g @login_required() vs using just @login_required

Tags: python, python-decorators

I've seen code such as

```
@login_required()
def user_profile(request):
    # do stuff here
```

I've also seen some code written as

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
    # do stuff here
```

Note the missing `()` in the second example.
On testing, both of them work the same. Is there any difference between the 2 approaches?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using python decorator with or without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572663/using-python-decorator-with-or-without-parentheses)

Comment: I'm voting to close, because @fsl has it right - note that the 2 options are something completely different: applying a decorator vs. calling a function that returns a decorator and applying that.

Comment: @fsl yes it does. Thank you