# Why is decorator called when decorated function is defined?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want a decorator which adds a function to any kind of function collection when defined.
My understanding of a decorator was that the decorator is called when the decorated function is called as in this example:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def inner():
        print("I am making things nicer")
        func()
    return inner

print("Function is defined")
@my_decorator
def my_function():
    print(f"I am doing something")

print("Function is called")
my_function()
```

Output:

```
Function is defined
Function is called
I am making things nicer
I am doing something
```

There are plenty of resources about how this works (`my_decorator(my_function)` ...).

However, if the inner function does not call but returns `f()`, then the decorator is called when the decorated function is defined.

```
def my_decorator(): 
    def inner(f):
        print("I am making things nicer")
        return f
    return inner

print("Function is defined")
@my_decorator()
def doing_something():
    print(f"I am doing something")

print("Function is called")
doing_something()
```

Output:

```
Function is defined  
I am making things nicer  
Function is called 
I am doing something
```

This is exactly what I want to achieve but I have no clue how it works. I also found out that it only works with additional parentheses (`@my_decorator()`) which for a normal decorator are not required.

My questions are:

- Is this a valid type of decorator?
- How does it work? Why is the decorator called when the function is defined?

Answer (score 0):

In your second example the decorator is "faulty" because it doesn't take the decorated function as a parameter. Another thing is that `inner` expects an argument (`f`) when `some_function` doesn't take any. "Traditionally" the decorator takes the decorated function as an argument and the inner function takes what ever arguments are passed to the decorated function. Why your code works the way it does is explained quite nicely here: [Using python decorator with or without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572663/using-python-decorator-with-or-without-parentheses)

To return the decorated function without calling it, or the decorator at definition, you would have to do something in between your 2 examples:

```py
def my_decorator(f):
    print("I will make things nicer")
    def inner():
        print("I am making things nicer")
        return f
    return inner

print("Function is defined")
@my_decorator
def doing_something():
    print("I am doing something")

print("Function is called")
f_ret = doing_something()
print("Function saved to variable")
f_ret()
```

Output :

```
Function is defined
I will make things nicer
Function is called
I am making things nicer
Function saved to variable
I am doing something
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I'll come back to this in the next few days