# When working with blueprints, why do decorators required brackets?

Tags: python, flask, python-decorators, flask-security

I have a blueprint app and I'm trying to integrate [Flask-Security-Too](https://github.com/Flask-Middleware/flask-security). In my blueprint I have two routes:

```
@core_bp.route("/")
@auth_required
def home():
   print("test")
   return render_template('/core_bp/index.html')


@core_bp.route("/get-projects")
@auth_required
def get_projects():
    searchTerm = request.args.get("search")
    data = [
        "buchsweg 5" ,
        "tannenweg 1"
    ]

return jsonify(data)
```

In this case I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: core_bp.wrapper
```

But when I replace `auth_required` with `@auth_required()` it's working just fine? It's working now, but it would be nice to understand why it's working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the parenthesis because there are 3 optional arguments that can be passed to the decorator as you can see here in line 275

https://github.com/Flask-Middleware/flask-security/blob/master/flask_security/decorators.py

In general `some_decorator` is a regular
decorator, whereas, `some_decorator()`  is a callable that returns a decorator as stated in this former question:

[Using python decorator with or without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572663/using-python-decorator-with-or-without-parentheses)