# why is the event duplicated? Disnake, DiscordPy

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, disnake

on_presence_update - Called when a Member updates their presence.

there is a code:

```
@bot.event()
async def on_presence_update(self,before,after):
    print('test')
```

And when the user's status is updated, the message "test" is sent 2 times. That is, it is called 2 times. Why? And how to fix it?

I’ll also add that this happens not only with this event.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By using parentheses with `bot.event`, you are not only listening for the event then calling the function, you are also calling the decorator. See [Decorators With or Without Parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572663/using-python-decorator-with-or-without-parentheses).

Just like the example given in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.event), you want to exclude the parentheses.

```
@bot.event
async def on_presence_update(self, before, after):
    print('test')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what should I do if I use `@commands.Cog.listener()`?

if I exclude the parentheses from `commands.Cog.listener` I get an error.
Error:
disnake.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.members_online_data' raised an error: TypeError: Cog.listener expected str or Enum but received 'function' instead.

Comment: You will need the parentheses. The difference here is that `@commands.Cog.listener()` is a function/callable. The error that you got is because you treated it as a decorator, which would take in a function. A rule of thumb would be to follow the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.listener).

Comment: To understand more about decorators and functions, you can take a look at the first link in my answer or the source code on github. This shows that `@commands.Cog.listener()` actually has a function inside its main function. With the parenthesis, you are calling the outer function, and using it as a decorator with `@` uses the inner function.

Comment: This allows it to take an argument within the parentheses, in this case would be the optional `name` argument. Then as a decorator, takes the function you're using it on as an argument.

Comment: TL;DR `bot.event` is a decorator, and `@commands.Cog.listener()` is a callable/function. These are extra information to help you understand decorators better, which can also be found in the first link in the answer.

Comment: It’s clear, now I know more about decorators and functions, but I still don’t understand how to get rid of event duplication in this case?

Comment: as it turns out, the event is duplicated in both `@bot.event` and `@commands.Cog.listener()`